# Android - how to add new value in arraylist of getter setter class

Tags: android, json, arraylist, getter-setter

I had a class name Calculator (getter-setter type class). I collect all values from json using volley jar. Now i want to add new value at zero index of arraylist. But I am not able to do that.
Here is code.

```
List<Calculator> currency;
```

Inside onCreate Method

```
currency = new ArrayList<Calculator>();
```

After that i call function to get values from json.

```
JSONArray jsonArray3 = jsonObject
                                .getJSONArray("currency");
                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray3.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject object = jsonArray3.getJSONObject(i);
                            String valueShow = object
                                    .getString("valueshow");
                            String valueID = object
                                    .getString("valueoption");
                            Log.e("", "-------CURRENCY----------");
                            Log.d("", "Show value : " + valueShow);
                            Log.d("", "Show ID    : " + valueID);
                            Log.e("", "-------------------------");
                            Calculator calculator = new Calculator(
                                    valueShow, valueID);
                            currency.add(calculator);
```

Now added to spinner. But at zero index I get currency name. 
I wish to add "Select Currency" at zero index.I use below code to get what i want

```
Calculator calculator = new Calculator();
currency.add(0, calculator.setValueShow("Select Currencies"));
```

It gives me error -

> The method add(int, Calculator) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (int, void)

Please help and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
currency.add(0, calculator.setValueShow("Select Currencies"));
```

line causing issue because `currency` takes `Calculator` object but currently trying to add `void` which is return from `calculator.setValueShow("Select Currencies")` method call. do it as:

```
calculator.setValueShow("Select Currencies");
currency.add(0, calculator);
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you add your calculator class here 
I think **calculator.setValueShow("Select Currencies")**

returns void